# Facebook Video Upload Public Video Issue

Tags: facebook, video, facebook-ios-sdk

I have had some success uploading videos from my iOS app.  I am able to confirm publish_action permissions and process with the upload.

```
ACFacebookPermissionsKey : @[@"email", @"user_videos", @"publish_actions"],
ACFacebookAudienceKey:ACFacebookAudienceEveryone};
```

Following the successful upload, I get a response from the Facebook API with the video_id.  I am storing this in a dB to access later since it's a public video.  So, when I inspect the video_ids returned - they appear different?

Videos uploaded via my app (logged in, public) have an ID similar to: **4239462546398**
Videos uploaded via the Facebook App (logged in, public) have an ID similar to: **10150495056083275**

So, I can access the Facebook App video uploads whether I am logged in to FB or not with the following URL:
*http://www.facebook.com/video/video.php?v=10150495056083275*

i CANNOT access the video uploaded via my iOS app with the video_id created by Facebook: 
*http://www.facebook.com/video/video.php?v=4239462546398*

I need to know what I am doing wrong on my video upload?  Even though I have it set to public, etc... I can't seem to see my videos????

Some details about my environment:

- Building for iOS 6
- Using iOS 6 FB Integration
- Uploading the video with SLRequest (successful request / response)

Here is my code for the video post if it helps (and it works)

```
- (void) uploadFBVideo2:(NSURL*) filePath
{
      ANVideoMashManager *videoMashManager = [ANVideoMashManager sharedManager];

      NSURL *videourl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/videos"];
      NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:filePath];

      NSDictionary *params = @{
        @"title": videoMashManager.videoStoryTitle,
        @"description": videoMashManager.videoDescTitle
      };

      SLRequest *uploadRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                              requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST
                                                        URL:videourl
                                                 parameters:params];
      [uploadRequest addMultipartData:videoData
                       withName:@"video"
                           type:@"video/mov"
                       filename:[filePath absoluteString]];

      uploadRequest.account = facebooAccount;

     [uploadRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
     NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
     if(error){
         NSLog(@"Video Upload ERROR: %@", error.localizedDescription);

     }else{
         NSLog(@"Video Upload SUCCESS: %@", responseString);
         NSDictionary* jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
         NSString *videoId = [jsonResponse objectForKey:@"id"];

     }

     }];
}
```

Comment: Which API are you using to make the upload? Is the video ID accessible via the API?

Comment: Yep, the ID in the post here are real.  I am using the 3.1 SDK... I can post more code from the app if you want.  What else do you think would be helpful to see?